# Como agregar validaciones a un arrayForm en Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, validación, validationerror

Intenté de esta manera agregar validación a algunas entradas dinámicas, pero no ha funcionado, agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Este es el HTML donde define el formulario con las entradas dinámicas establecidas en el ts, donde si no se completa la entrada se debe activar el mat error indicando que el campo es requerido.

HTML

```
<div formArrayName="dynamic_fields" >
  <div *ngFor="let field of dynamicFields; let i = index">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input
        matInput
        [formControlName]="i"
        [type]="field.type"
        [placeholder]="field.name"
      />
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-error *ngIf="i.hasError('required')">
      Este campo es requerido
    </mat-error>
  </div>
</div>
```

Este es el ts donde defino la inicialización del formulario y pongo la validación para que todos los campos sean obligatorios.

TS
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamicForm',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic-form.component.scss'],
})
export class DynamicFormComponent implements OnInit {

  public dynamicFields: any;
  public form: FormGroup;
  public fields: any = [
    {
      name: 'name',
      type: 'text'
    },
    {
      name: 'atributte',
      type: 'text'
    },
    {
      name: 'grade',
      type: 'number'
    }
  ]

  constructor( private fb: FormBuilder ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.start();
  }


  start() {

    this.form = this.fb.group({})

      this.dynamicFields = this.fields
      console.log(this.dynamicFields)
      if (this.dynamicFields) {
        this.form.addControl(
          'dynamic_fields',
          this.fb.array(
            this.dynamicFields?.map(x => {
              this.fb.control(x.name, Validators.required);
            }, {}) || []
          )
        );
      }

  }

}
```

Agradeceria mucho su ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No te lo muestra por 2 motivos:

El primero, como te ha dicho Pablo en su respuesta, es porque estas basando el hasError del ngIf en el número del index y  no en el `FormControl`.
Según tienes el código deberías hacer algo así para que te funcione:

```
*ngIf="form.get('dynamic_fields.' + i).hasError('required')"
```

---

Y el segundo error, es que desde la función del `map` donde generas los controles del array, no estas haciendo `return`. Así que tendrás o bien que añadir el `return`

```
this.dynamicFields?.map(x => {
  return this.fb.control('', Validators.required);
})
```

O eliminar las llaves

```
this.dynamicFields?.map(x => this.fb.control('', Validators.required))
```

un saludo

Answer (score 0):

En tu plantilla HTML tienes:

```
<div *ngFor="let field of dynamicFields; let i = index">
    ...
    <mat-error *ngIf="i.hasError('required')">
      Este campo es requerido
    </mat-error>
  </div>
</div>
```

Es decir, estás accediendo a `i` (un número) en lugar de a `field` para comprobar si tiene errores.